# How to change the color of dots indicator (both active and inactive) per fragment in viewpager?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewpager

[A picture of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfIRI.png)

I've set the colors of the active and inactive states of the dot indicator using XML. However I am very confused as to how to change the colors of the active and inactive state per screen as shown in the image.
I have created the layouts using fragments and viewpager and I've added a tablayout.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val adapter = MyViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment(TakeFragment())
        adapter.addFragment(UploadFragment())
        adapter.addFragment(PaidFragment())
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

    }

    class MyViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager){

        val fragmentList : MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            return fragmentList[position]
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return fragmentList.size
        }

        fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment){
            fragmentList.add(fragment)
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</FrameLayout>
```

**tab_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_dot"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_dot"/>
</selector>
```

**selected_dot.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="8dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#8EBFE8"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**default_dot.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="8dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#AAD6F9"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: refer this-->https://droidmentor.com/create-onboard-screens-using-viewpager/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for simplicity, say you have implemented ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener

```
@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int i) {
        Log.v(TAG, " ++++++++    onPageSelected:  " + i);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);

        //TODO You can use this position: to write other dependent logic
        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.println("0");
            mImv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activate_one);
            mImv2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_one);

        } else {
            System.out.println("1");
            mImv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_one);
            mImv2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activate_one);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hey, what are mImv1 and mImv2 here?

Comment: is there a way to change the color of it without using 2 separate drawables?

Answer (score 1):

```
private int dotsCount;
private ImageView[] dots;

private void addViewPagerDots() {

    dotsCount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotsCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
        dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_dot));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        params.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);

        final int presentPosition = i;
        dots[presentPosition].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(presentPosition);
                return true;
            }

        });
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i], params);
    }
    dots[0].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_dot));


}
```